# Apache - How to protect virtualhost directive without htaccess

Tags: apache, location, virtualhost, password-protection

I would like to password protect port 2000 of a web server by embedding a location directive inside of the virtualhost directive of the apache config file. However it didn't prompt for a password as expected. This is what I had in the apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:2000>
  ServerName www.server.com
  ServerAdmin email
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ErrorLog logs/server.com-error_log

  <Location / >
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Security"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/s2/.htpasswd-users
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple reasons why I think it didn't work:

1. I needed a corresponding NameVirtualHost *:2000 to go with the VirtualHost directive
2. I was using a reverse ssh tunnel on that port so ssh was catching it before the web server.  The web server that the tunnel connected to did not have password protection.

So now my question is how to password protect the server at the end of the tunnel.  It is a simple server and not capable of passwords.  That's why I was hoping to protect access to it via the apache server.

Answer (score 0):

[AuthType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype) only works inside  or in a .htaccess file:

You have it inside a  and that's the rease it isn't working.